Problem with print multiple page ordering
I'm trying to print a PDF from the document viewer on Ubuntu 24.04 on a scale of 9 pages by page.
I have the page ordering option set on "left to right top to bottom" but if I start the print directly, it makes the order from the right to the left. I need to show the preview and then print to have the correct order.
Does someone know anything about this issue ?
My printer is a Ricoh SP C250SF and it prints on Universal PCL6 mode.
